# How to add image from iPhone gallery to an array IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

As I am very much new to iOS development, I am trying to add an uiimage from image gallery to an array. But when I try to use the array to add image to uiimageview it shows me an error

> [UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fefd3ea02f0.

```
choosen_Imgae = info[ UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
// 
// choosen_Imgae = [self resizeImage:choosen_Image];
NSLog(@"chosen image %@",choosen_Imgae); 
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; 
NSData *dataImage = [[NSData alloc] init]; 
dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(choosen_Imgae); 
if (dataImage != nil) { 
    [image_Arr insertObject:choosen_Imgae atIndex:indexxpath.row];
    NSLog(@"image array after adding object %@",image_Arr);
}
```

Comment: You need to share some code then we can help you.

Comment: fetching image from gallery adding it to image array

Comment: you need to append in array rather inserting at specific index. If your array is allocated with fixed size than you can use `insertObject:atIndex:` else use  `addObject:` method. Also make sure before using any of this your array is initialised properly.

Comment: ashish check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Brother simply you can add the image to array.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   UIImage *choosen_Imgae=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
   [image_Arr addObject:image];
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you use NSData in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo,it is long process(image->NSData).When fetching image from array again you have to convert NSData into image.So you can directly save the image into array.
Also you don't need to use insertObject to array.

When fetch the image from array

```
for (int i=0; i<[image_Arr count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *fetch_Image = [image_Arr objectATIndex:i];
    imageView.image = fetch_Image;
}
```